# CREATE INDEX ONLINE = ON - unreplicated table - blocking Replication

Tags: sql-server, locking, database-replication

SQL 2008 Ent SP3.

Hi - We were attempting to deploy a new nonclustered index to a table.  The database has about 100 (of 2000+) replicated tables.  The table receiving the new index is not replicated, and in fact resides on a separate file group from most of the replicated tables in the database.  Index was also created in the separate filegroup.

CREATE INDEX statement was ONLINE = ON.  The index candidate is very narrow (one datetime column), and the table is clustered on a BIGINT primary key.  The table is huge with nearly 1 billion rows.

What we saw was that replication was blocked for 30-40 seconds, then the blocks would release for 30-40 seconds.  This process would continually repeat itself.  Replication latency skyrocketed.  No other process had any traffic to the table that was receiving the index (it is presently updated nightly by a batch job, which was complete before the CREATE INDEX started).

I don't have the types of locks that the CREATE INDEX statement held, my off-hours DBA did not capture this information.  Nothing like this was seen in lower environments.

Just trying to get an idea why this isolated table receiving a nonclustered index would block replication.  Any thoughts?

Thanks
John.

Comment: Have you tried creating the index using `ONLINE = OFF`?  Is that an option?

Comment: Hi - not an option in this case - if we are getting intermittent locks in an ONLINE=ON scenario, I fear taking a long lock that would block everything..